# Defining an array as an .env variable in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I have an array that I pull data from.

```
BLOCK_IP_LIST = [127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3]
```

**I'm not sure how to do that.**

I have Use .env BLOCK_IP_LIST in BlockIpMiddleware using Config>app.php

**Config.app.php** code like

```
'block_ip' => env('BLOCK_IP_LIST'),
```

my **BlockIpMiddleware** Code Like

```
class BlockIpMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $blockIps = config('app.block_ip');

        if (in_array($request->ip(), $blockIps)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => "You don't have permission to access this website."]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `BlockIpMiddleware` is alright

but `.env` should look like that

```
BLOCK_IP_LIST=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3
```

Inside `app.php`

```
'block_ip' => explode(',', env('BLOCK_IP_LIST')),
```

[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) find `,` and convert from string to array.

---

#### My opinion

You should do it with the database and cache it forever Because you/client can add/delete the IPs as you want and anytime.

Answer (score 4):

you can save your data as json in your .env file

```
BLOCK_IP_LIST={"127.0.0.1","192.168.1.2"}
```

and in your controller you can access your data using

```
$black_lists = json_decode(env('BLOCK_IP_LIST'));
```

Comment: IMO this answer is better than the accepted answer because the accepted answer cannot handle empty arrays, so if you had BLAH= in your env file with no value assigned, explode(',', '') would yield [''], which is not the intended value. However, if you're happy to designate an empty array in your env file with BLAH=[] (which I think is a good idea because it tells the next dev information about how to populate the variable if they need to use it), when you json_decode() it you will end up with the empty array, as specified in the env file. So I think this a better general purpose solution.

Comment: @JamesG I agree with you that JSON looks like a much cleaner solution, but I don't understand why would anyone put an empty variable in the first place. Have you found yourself in this situation before ?

Comment: It might be set to a blank value in .env.dev or .env.testing, which might cause an  unexpected result. Although that is a highly unlikely possibility, my point is more than the json version solves the problem and also handles this case, whereas the explode option doesn't handle this case. So if you want a solution that is closer to perfect (even if you don't *need* perfect) then the json solution is better. Having said that, the json version requires a lot more characters and contains more visual clutter, which itself can be undesirable, because it can make errors in the data harder to spot.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad to store array in `.env` files as it is meant to hold small text values only, storing and array of string, will most likely means this list will grow overtime.
but to answer your question there is a hack to get it done.

.ENV file

```
BLOCK_IP_LIST = "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3"
```

Now for your `Config > app.php` file:

```
'block_ip' => explode(',', env('BLOCK_IP_LIST')),
```

That should get you up and running, remember to clear your config cache.